# fatal error: eigen3/Eigen/Core: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cython, eigen, eigen3

I am not aware of C++ but I am trying to run this [project](https://github.com/speedinghzl/DSRG) which says to create a wrapper by running the command `pip install CRF/`. I am trying to do the same but I am running into this error.

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-pmpk49o5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-pmpk49o5/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ytpsnw2f --python-tag cp36
       cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-pmpk49o5/
  Complete output (30 lines):
  Warning: Extension name 'krahenbuhl2013/wrapper' does not match fully qualified name 'krahenbuhl2013.wrapper' of 'krahenbuhl2013/wrapper.pyx'
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/krahenbuhl2013
  copying krahenbuhl2013/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/krahenbuhl2013
  copying krahenbuhl2013/CRF.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/krahenbuhl2013
  running build_ext
  building 'krahenbuhl2013/wrapper' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/krahenbuhl2013
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Iinclude -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c krahenbuhl2013/wrapper.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/krahenbuhl2013/wrapper.o
  In file included from /home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1830:0,
                   from /home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                   from /home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                   from krahenbuhl2013/wrapper.cpp:438:
  /home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
   #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
    ^
  In file included from krahenbuhl2013/../include/densecrf.h:29:0,
                   from krahenbuhl2013/../include/densecrf_wrapper.h:1,
                   from krahenbuhl2013/wrapper.cpp:440:
  krahenbuhl2013/../include/unary.h:28:29: fatal error: eigen3/Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
   #include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
                               ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for CRF
```

Initially it was `#include <Eigen/Core>` but I followed this [discussion](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14868) and changed it to `eigen3/Eigen/Core`. But I am getting the same error in both cases. As a person with extremely limited knowledge in c++, what should I do to resolve this error.

Comment: Did you install the dependencies using `pip install -r python-dependencies.txt` as mentioned in the documentation. https://github.com/speedinghzl/DSRG#installing-dependencies

Comment: I have all the libraries mentioned in that file. Just wondering if we have to install the `libeigen3-dev` package for eigen??

Comment: > Fully connected CRF wrapper (requires the Eigen3 package).

Answer (score 1):

You obviously need to have Eigen installed (`libeigen3-dev` on many Linuxes) -- or download it manually.

Furthermore,

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
```

instead of

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
```

is not recommended. You should rather pass the correct include path to your compiler. With clang/gcc on many common Linux distributions this is `-I/usr/include/eigen3` (which you already seem to do).

If you downloaded Eigen manually, you need to adapt that path to where you have the (extracted) Eigen directories.